# Watch a filesystem and rsync changes in a cross-platform way with minimal dependencies

Tags: linux, windows, python, rsync, cross-platform

I'd like to start a long-running Ruby or Python script, and have the script watch a local directory for changes to files and new files. Periodically, the script will trigger a one-way rsync to a remote network location.

This must function on both Linux (Ubuntu 13.10+) and Windows (Windows 7+) environments. Importantly, I'd like to minimize the number of dependencies required, and I'd like to install the same thing on every system by simply dropping some files in a directory -- no installer.

Is it possible to get the system I'm describing want without an installer? If so, how?

Comment: just fyi, rsync has an option to monitor for changes.

Comment: @RickyBeam: I have to monitor the changes in a programmatic way that isn't suitable for rsync's command-line options. But thanks for the heads-up!

Comment: @RickyBeam does it really? how?

Answer (score 1):

In the past, when I was doing this from windows platform to any other system that supports a sshd or sftp, I used [WinSCP](https://winscp.net/eng/index.php) which has very well written sync features.  WinSCP can also be executed from the command line to watch a local directory and automatically push and/or pull files to a remote file system via SCP or SFTP protocols.

The WinSCP solution is very robust and highly configurable but its written for windows.

I have gotten WinSCP to install on my linux machine using 32 bit wine and it works reasonably well, although, I have not tried running the sync feature from CLI on linux yet. I am confident I will have the CLI working on linux shortly once I have the time to focus on that.

[update] The one caveat of WinSCP, it does not handle Symbolic links well. In my usecases, I want it to ignore symlinked directories but send symlinked files as actual files but the WinSCP sync function ignores them once the file exists on the remote system.

Answer (score 0):

As a possible solution to the first part of your question, you should take a look at [inotify-tools](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki), this contains the tool [inotifywait](https://github.com/rvoicilas/inotify-tools/wiki#wiki-inotifywait) which watches a directory (or set of directories recursively) and outputs notifications of changes (these can be restricted to certain event types, e.g. file creation, deletion, modification etc.). More information can be found on the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/1/inotifywait).

I'm not familiar with programming (python or otherwise) on Windows machines, but there has been a port of inotifywait for Windows in the form of [inotify-win](https://github.com/thekid/inotify-win) which, after having produced the executable, you can presumably run from a script via [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) with minimal platform-specific changes from the Linux version.

For the second part of your question, you could go for SFTP using [paramiko](https://github.com/paramiko/paramiko), however, it seems that the dependency on [PyCrypto](https://www.dlitz.net/software/pycrypto/) may make this option a bit challenging from a Windows point of view.

I realise this isn't a complete answer to all the parts of your question, but hopefully there is something here that you find useful.

Answer (score 0):

I've heard good things about https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog - a Python library for the monitoring of filesystem events that works on Linux, OSX, FreeBSD and Windows.

I would use something like bbfreeze or pyinstaller to package your whole tool up into binaries for the various different platforms. rsync already has installers for most systems.

Answer (score 0):

If you are to build a custom script in Python, I would consider using [AsyncSSH](https://github.com/ronf/asyncssh). The async nature would aid in making a very fast tool and it has all the features needed to access a remote system securely.

The only limitation is that the remote system needs an SSH daemon, but this is getting much easier to do these days and I've heard that newest windows even has an out of the box SSH daemon coming.

I'm presently on the fence on whether to build such a tool myself.